# Ruby - how to find the NEXT occurrence of a given hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, time

I want to return a Ruby `Time` object (miliseconds) that represents the next X hour from a given DateTime.

Examples for the next 5am

- if it currently is 9pm on 3/28, the NEXT 5am would be 3/29 5am
- if it currently is 6am on 3/29, the NEXT 5am would be 3/30 5am

Code wise:

```
# for the below attribute
@object.created_at
=> "2017-03-28 21:00:00"

# given the definition of the next X hour in question
next_hour_to_find = 5 # for 5am

# what's the equation to produce 3/29 5am?
```

I'd like something flexible so that if `next_hour_to_find = 14` then the function would be able to find the next 2pm. No worries about time zone, this is all within the scope of the time zone of the `@object.created_at`.

My current thinking is below, but I feel like there's a cleaner way...

```
if @object.created_at.hour > next_hour_to_find
  # the next X hour is always going to occur on the next date
  date = (@object.created_at + 1.days).strftime(...) # get the date out
else
  # the next X hour is always going to occur on the same date
  date = (@object.created_at).strftime(...) # get the date out
end

# now that we have a date in a string, we have to append that string with the next_hour_to_find
# not sure if below works for both single and double digit hours
string = date + next_hour_to_find + ":00:00"

# finish by returning Time object, but this seems suuuuper inefficient since we converted to string and then back again
return Time.parse(string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to smash around with string-formatted times. The DateTime object has everything you need:

```
now = DateTime.now

if (now.hour >= 5)
  now = now.advance(days: 1)
end

now.change(hour: 5)
```

Comment: did not know about those methods... amazing

Comment: @james ActiveSupport adds a bunch of very nice tools to the Date/Time/DateTime classes that Ruby should eventually steal and make core. They're tremendously useful.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic), which is a great lib that allows for natural language when working with dates in Ruby.

```
five_today = Chronic.parse('5am')
five_today < Time.now ? Chronic.parse('tomorrow 5am') : five_today
```

Since Chronic returns regular `Date` and `Time` objects, this would also work without it. You're left with a less pleasant syntax, however.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
def next_hour_from(time, next_hour_to_find)
  hour_on_day_of_time = next_hour_to_find.hours.since( time.beginning_of_day )
  hour_on_day_of_time < time ? 1.day.since(hour_on_day_of_time) : hour_on_day_of_time
end

# e.g.
next_hour_from(@object.created_at, 5) # @object.created_at #=> 2017-03-28 21:00:00
# => 2017-03-29 05:00:00
```

Basically what it does is:

- It looks at the time at the beginning of the day of `time`, and adds `next_hour_to_find` to it, in hours. Assigns that value to `hour_on_day_of_time`.
- Then checks to see if that `hour_on_day_of_time` is before or after the given `time`. If it's after, then the method can just return `hour_on_day_of_time`. If it's before, it adds 1 day to `hour_on_day_of_time` and returns that.

Comment: just loved how simplistic tadman's answer is though i quickly skimmed and this is same concept so should work too

Comment: Honestly, I agree. Just wanted to add a different potential solution to consider. I would also suggest looking at Chronic as @coreyward proposes. If nothing else, it makes things easy to understand, and that's valuable in itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure-Ruby answer. I assume a 24-hour clock. If a 12-hour clock is desired the 12-hour time (e.g `3pm`) can be converted (to `15`) as a preliminary step.

```
require 'time'

dt = DateTime.now
  #=> #<DateTime: 2017-03-31T00:18:08-07:00\
  #     ((2457844j,26288s,566004000n),-25200s,2299161j)>
```

Suppose

```
next_hr = 15
```

Then

```
Time.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour) +
  3600 * ((dt.hour < next_hr) ? next_hr - dt.hour : 24 + next_hr - dt_hour)
  #> 2017-03-31 15:00:00 -0700
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a more sophisticated solution for my use case:

```
def resolve_time str
  time_string, locality_string = str.split(/ +/)
  locality_string ||= ENV['TZ'] # or however you default your TZ, the locality string is ie 'UTC', 'Europe/Stockholm', 'CET', ...
  zone_string = Time.now.in_time_zone(locality_string).zone
  rv = DateTime.strptime("#{time_string} #{zone_string}", '%H:%M %Z')

  if rv < Time.now
    rv = rv.advance(days: 1)
  end

  rv
end
```

It accepts input as a string with or without the time zone. In my case this was necessary.